# Rails ActionMailer attachment in rake task not working as expected

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In a rake test I am invoking ActionMailer::Base this way:

```
namespace :mine do
  desc "it sends emails"
  mailer = ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => 'whoever', :to => 'whoemever', :subject => "hi        there") do |format|
    format.text do
      render :text => 'my list'
    end
  end
  mailer.attachments['myfile.csv'] = { :content => File.read('/tmp/file.csv'),
                                             :mime_type => 'text/csv'
                                           }
  mailer.deliver
end
```

The mail gets sent, however the attachment gets put into the body of the email..looks something like this:

```
— Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2013 16:26:25 -0400 Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/csv;

charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Content-Disposition: attachment;

filename=my_file.csv
```

and then the dump of the file. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Could it be that whatever client you're using to view the mail is presenting the attachment this way and the attachment is in fact correct, as you specified it?

Comment: it doesnt seem that way. i've tried sparrow, apple mail and gmail in the browser :/

Comment: As an experiment, you might want to try sending it as an inline attachment (`attachments.inline[...]=`) and see if the behavior is the same. I couldn't find anywhere where the default could be sent to inline, however.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin so i found a solution. I had to create a separate mailer class with a view. that seemed to work for some reason. not really sure why this didnt